# Issues with kml layer containing various points

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, kml, infowindow

I am doing a web application using google map api v 3. I have an kml layer overlay google map. The kml layer was developed using qgis connected to my database. Now I have two issues:

1. Why the info window is empty on click of the marker, shouldn't have the info taken from  the database?
2. can I change the icon of each point from a marker?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Can't tell from the information you have posted why the infowindow is empty.  Either (a.) the css is set up so the text is white or (b.) the content (name/description) in the KML is empty.  If that doesn't help, please post a link to your KML or a snippet from your KML.
2. KML provides the ability to control the icons displayed, see [the reference](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html)

Comment: I have just noted that the content (name/description) was empty @geocodezip